# How to write better Python code: Replace multiple elif by what?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

what is Pythons best practice for multiple elifs?
I would like to write the following function in a more beautiful or structured way. Is there anything like switch case built in? How would a pro structure this? I am still beginner :-)
Thanks in advance!

```
def getThreshold(i=0.00):
    if i <= 500:
        return i * 1.1
    elif i <= 1000:
        return i * 1.4
    elif i <= 2000:
        return i * 1.1
    elif i <= 3000:
        return i
    elif i <= 5000:
        return i * 0.85
    elif i <= 10000:
        return i * 0.7
    elif i <= 20000:
        return i * 0.7
    elif i <= 100000:
        return i * 0.75
    else:
        return i * 0.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite clear, but it's a repetition of a single idea: check for an inequality and return something. Moreover, I would split data and logic. Why not doing the following then?
def getThreshold(i=0.00):

```
rules = [
  { threshold: 500, value: 1.1 },
  { threshold: 1000, value: 1.4 },
  { threshold: 2000, value: 1.1 },
  { threshold: 3000, value: 1.0 },
  { threshold: 5000, value: 0.85 },
  { threshold: 10000, value: 0.7 },
  { threshold: 20000, value: 0.7 },
  { threshold: 100000, value: 0.75 },
  { threshold: math.inf, value: 0.8 },
];    

for rule in rules:
   if i <= rule.threshold:
       return rule.value
```

I hope it helps. Please flag my comment as valid answer if it does.

Comment: This is brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!!

Comment: Solid idea, but this doesn't look like valid python..

Comment: Right. I took the idea and modified it. Going through a list of tuples and it's beautiful!! 

Comment: @Dennis I am glad you are happy with my answer. Would you mind flagging it as the valid answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
def getThreshold(i = 0.0):
    lm = [(500, 1.1), (1000, 1.4), (2000, 1.1), (3000,1), (5000, 0.85), (10000, 0.7), (20000, 0.7 ), (100000, 0.75)]
    for l, f in lm:
        if i <= l:
            return i*f
        
    return i*0.8
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I more or less ended up with. Thanks!